# MODIS HDF to Corrected Reflectance Bands 7-2-1. Change Reflectance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, hdf

Convert HDF to Tiff easily. But I can not get the images to 7-2-1 bands.

Like this :

[image: Ice on the Great Lakes. 26 February, 2014]

How can I get this image from HDF and what product should I use (MYD09GQ and etc)? Maybe using ArcGIS?

Comment: Are you trying to display a false color composite?

Comment: Yea, but can not imagine how. Example - http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gallery/individual.php?db_date=2014-02-26

Comment: Have you tried assigning individual bands to RGB in the ArcGIS table of contents?

Comment: Based on your title, keep in mind that reassigning band combinations is much different than altering reflectance.